Can I teleport from an Outlaw System to a regular one?
Every outlaw system has an outlaw station with a teleporter. Usually they let you teleport between space stations, bases or settlements, but not these. Every destination is listed, but it's blocked like I'm missing some kind of authorization.
What's the purpose of a teleporter I can't use? Is it only used to teleport between outlaw systems?
Because I'm missing the point to have several destinations if I can't choose them.
Do they eventually become available doing something specific?

The "blocked network" restriction is just a time waster.
No, you won't "unlock" anything to remove the restriction. But you can simply workaround the restriction in the first place.
The key is that no teleporter will ever prevent you from teleporting to your own base. You can easily see the result of this gimmick.
Outlaw Space Station-> Base -> Regular Space Station
Coincidentally, by doing so you also avoided any form of actual flying in your ship - which is the only time you can get scanned and fined / attacked for carrying items that are considered "illegal cargo".
Even more importantly, this technically allows you to go to an outlaw system, buy all the tech packages spending units , open them and sell the modules for nanites at the regular stations, making out for a ridiculous fast "nanite farm" that puts most "curious deposit" into shame if you can bother creating a "large enough" network.

Update: since pinckerman mentioned that they think they saw their base coming up as restricted too, I will point out that some players had reported similar bugs, usually without any visual proof. I can't confirm if the bug is real or just some form of Mandela Effect. Anyway, just in case, remember that the Anomaly teleporter is unrestricted too.

I can confirm I can teleport to each of my bases and also my settlements, and of course from my base back to the outlaw system
